# Generate date from sunday except the existing value, in 1 Week Range

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the result of my query right now with data getting 1 result only.

[image]
This is my query: 
$merid=20;

```
SELECT SUM(orders.total) as weektotal , DAYNAME(orders.payment_date) as dayname, 
orders.*, customers.first_name, customers.last_name, customers.contact, customers.email, 
addresses.address, addresses.remarks FROM orders 
INNER JOIN customers ON customers.id = orders.member_id 
INNER JOIN add1 ON add1.custom_id = customers.id 
WHERE orders.status = 'Complete'  AND orders.seller_id ='$merid' 
AND orders.payment_date >= NOW() + INTERVAL -7 DAY 
GROUP BY DATE(orders.payment_date) ORDER BY orders.id ASC
```

I am trying to populate to get the dates the full week beginning Sunday except the existing Tuesday .

[image]

Can someone give guidelines on where to begin?
Is the logical process can be done here in SQL or do I need to create the logic using PHP?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Generate base dates table in CTE or subquery then LEFT JOIN your data table to it.

Comment: Please show us your actual query, not just the result it produces.

Comment: @GMB, posted, and edited it

Comment: The progress I made to find a way. I think what I need to do is get all the SUNDAY from the CURRDATE,  with an INTERVAL of 7 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive subquery to generate the datename you want:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select date('2020-12-20') as dte 
      union all
      select dte + interval 1 day
      from dates
      where dte < '2020-12-26'
     )
select d.dte, dayname(d.dte), q.id, 
       coalesce(q.weektotal, 0) as weektotal
from dates d left join
     (<your query here>) q
     on q.date_time >= d.dte and
        q.date_time < d.dte + interval 1 day;
```

Comment: thank you , I thought of something I think what I need to do is get all the SUNDAY from the CURRDATE, with an INTERVAL of 7 days.  after your comment I realized I havent posted the query.

Comment: I UPDATED THE QUERY :

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own calendar and join with it

Example:

Calendar

| date | dayname |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-20 | Sunday |
| 2020-12-21 | Monday |
| 2020-12-22 | Tuesday |
| 2020-12-23 | Wednesday |
| 2020-12-24 | Thursday |
| 2020-12-25 | Friday |
| 2020-12-26 | Saturday |

OriginalTable:

| weektotal | dayname | id | date_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10820 | Tuesday | 6 | 2020-12-22 |

you can simply *left join* OriginalTable to Calendar table and apply COALESCE for desired columns for desired date interval

Comment: thank you , I thought of something I think what I need to do is get all the SUNDAY from the CURRDATE, with an INTERVAL of 7 days. after your answer I realized I havent posted the query.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

CREDITS TO  the answer of Gordon Linoff!! @Gordon Linoff